# How to clean pandas data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

***Absolutely for learning or personal use.***
When webscraping got required data in an unformatted way.

```
[['0     1'],
['10 John Doe 2'],
['21 Mike 3'],
['46 Symon 4'],
['54 Martyn Dave'],
['  5'],
['137 Hero           '],
['          '],
['          ']]
```

Hope to get the dataframe formatted as

```
[['10 John Doe'],
['21 Mike'],
['46 Symon'],
['54 Martyn Dave'],
['137 Hero]]
```

Comment: Please format your post more. As it is, it's hard to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use map with lambda to clear whitespaces for each element in your list. Then select just elements that are not empty:

```
import re
print([[each_element] for each_element in map(lambda x:x[0].strip(), my_list) if each_element != "" and not re.match("^ *[0-9][0-9 ]*$", each_element)])
```

The output:

```
[['10 John Doe 2'], ['21 Mike 3'], ['46 Symon 4'], ['54 Martyn Dave'], ['137 Hero']]
```

If you also want to remove the numbers from those strings, you can again use re as:

```
import re
print([[re.sub(r"\d+", "", each_element).strip()] for each_element in map(lambda x:x[0].strip(), my_list) if each_element != "" and not re.match("^ *[0-9][0-9 ]*$", each_element)])
```

And the output will be:

```
[['John Doe'], ['Mike'], ['Symon'], ['Martyn Dave'], ['Hero']]
```

Comment: It helped. Thanks. Also, I wanted to remove the int behind in the string - 10 John Doe 2

Comment: @RaaghavK You are welcome. However, in StackOverflow people thanks each other by voting and selecting the response as the best answer.

Comment: @RaaghavK Please show that in a sample.